# Not able to get price in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1.7

By providing $product->getPrice() the result which I get is 29.0000. How can I fetch the price in correct format along with currency i.e $29. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By default product object return as float price value without currency symbol.**

You can get price format with below syntax,

```
echo $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency( $product->getPrice(),true,false);
```

Using above syntax you can get price with currency format.

Comment: Could you tell me how can I get product url?

Comment: $product->getProductUrl()

Comment: But that didn't work for me.